# C error parsing in Eclipe-Indigo is not functioning

Tags: c, eclipse, syntax-error, settings, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to migrate some C programs from Windows Server to Linux. To edit the code, I'm using Eclipse-Indigo. The machine on which I'm working has WinXP on it (not my choice, so no comments please). My eclipse workarea is on a samba shared drive which is in my home directory on the Linux server.

Each C program is in a separate makefile project. I have specified the cygwin gcc compiler/parser in the settings for new CDT Projects and selected all relevant error parsers in the makefile project settings.

There are no syntax errors showing and the errors that are listed seem somewhat bizarre. The first error states:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../../../../../fiscus/vo/src/mk/e12_.mk'.  Stop.
```

The make script at the end is wrong. There is a value in the name which comes from an environment variable. The path is correct exactly as shown but the script name has hte variable `$(WA_PLATFORM)` in it. This is not being resolved although I have specified the value in the build environment variables.

The subsequent errors are even weirder. For each subsequent project I get the message:

```
Program "make" is not found in PATH
```

This makes me wonder how the first message was generated. Besides, the path on my winXP environment, which I assume is the relevant one here, does indeed have the directory with the make program in it.

Where have I mucked it up? Any hints?

One last piece of information. When I shut down eclipse I get access violation errors for the following:

```
<workarea-path>\.metadata\plugins\org.eclipse.debug.ui\launchConfigurationHistory.xml  
<workarea-path>\.metadata\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core\variablesAndContainers.dat
```

I find this to be suspicious...

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to lie in the fact that I was using the samba share as my workarea. Apparently the regular backups made on the server changed something (don't know exactly what, though). The projects were no longer being recognised as makefile projects and certain essential metadata files were not accessible. The permissions certainly were not the problem, since I checked those on the server (everything was set to rwxrwxrwx).

To solve the problem I copied the entire workarea to my local hard drive. I then pointed eclipse at this new workarea. The next step was a bit of a pain, because I had to delete each project (without deleting the source, of course) and then import "Existing code as Makefile Project". This can be done with "File->import..." or with a right-click in the package explorer and select "import...".

The last requirement is to specify the required "include" directories. This can be done with "Project-> Properties-> C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols". Select the "Includes" tab, choose the language (in this case "GNU C") and add the directories where the headers are defined.

Now it works properly again.